# regex (in flex) for complete general sentence

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am definig tokens inside flex as

```
%%

@[^\\\"  \n\(\),=\{\}#~]+              {yylval.sval = strdup(yytext + 1); return ENTRYTYPE;}
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9:"]*                   { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return KEY; }
\"([^"]|\\.)*\"|\{([^"]|\\.)*\}        { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
[ \t\n]                                ; /* ignore whitespace */
[{}=,]                                 { return *yytext; }
.                                      { fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized character %c in input\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

(Though, not a good way)
The problem is the VALUE variable are doing fine for a quoted string, of the form "some quote"; but not for the form when they are enclosed by braces (of the form {some sentences}) as tried.
What is messy there?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want this, instead:

```
\"([^"]|\\.)*\"|\{([^\}]|\\.)*\}        { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
```

Even better, the following will be clearer and easier to maintain:

```
\"([^"]|\\.)*\"                         { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
\{([^\}]|\\.)*\}                        { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
```

**Update**

I have escaped the right brace in the character class expressions.

Comment: `\"([^"]|\\.)*\"    { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
\{([^}]|\\.)*\}                        { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }`

is giving error for brace enclosed text as
**[bold]**syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting KEY or '}' **